# Condição IF em DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2017, navegador-de-internet

Olá.

Como posso realizar uma verificação do primeiro número de um row de um grid ?

Exemplo:

```
 If Conversions.ToString(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)[0(primeiro número da row)] == (for igual a:) 5  Then 
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ibMaster").InvokeMember("click")
If Conversions.ToString(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)[0(primeiro número da row)] == (for igual a:) 4  Then
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ibFitness").InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: Não percebi a sua questão... o que considera o "_primeiro número de um row de um grid_"? Pode desenvolver mais a sua questão?

Comment: Seria o primeiro número da primeira coluna  do datagrid, segue print: http://prntscr.com/khdr5g

Comment: Aí tipo, o programa verificaria: `Se (o primeiro número da coluna for) == 1 Then Variável a (string) = "ibMestre" End`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava quase lá no código que colocou na sua questão!

```
If Convert.ToString(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)(0) = "5" Then
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ibMaster").InvokeMember("click")
ElseIf Convert.ToString(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)(0) = "4" Then
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ibFitness").InvokeMember("click")
End If
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Como posso fazer a verificação dos seis primeiros digitos ? Exemplo: `ElseIf Convert.ToString(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)(0 até 6) = "530032" Then ... `

Comment: Penso que basta no fim colocar "SubString(0, 6)".

Comment: Aparece esse erro: "SubString não está declarado" `ElseIf Convert.ToString(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)(SubString(0, 6)) ... ` Consegui deste jeito: `ElseIf Convert.ToString(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value).SubString(0, 6)`

Comment: Exato, e era assim que tinha que utilizar o `Substring()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Podes por isso no eveneto click do botão:

```
For Each dg As DataGridViewRow In DGV_LANCAMENTO.Rows
    If dg.Cells(0).Value.ToString() = " valor em causa" Then
    End I
Next
```